# Do I need to create separate classes for request and response C#?

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, xamarin, request

how to make the parameters of the function or class?

```
 var list = await _service.GetAllNewsByParams( new NewsGetAllParams
        {
            Category = 1,
            From = _From,
            OrderBy = _OrderBy,
            Page = _Page,
            To = _To
        });
```

or

```
 var list = await _service.GetAllNewsByParams(
                                          _To,
                                         _OrderBy,
                                         _From, _Page,
                                         _SeletedNewsTagId);
```

and Do I need to create a class for each method in service

```
public async Task<IList<NewsSentimentIndexes>> getNewsSentimentIndexes()//new class NewsSentimentIndexes
public async Task<IList<News>> getNewsSentimentIndexes()//new class News
public async Task<IList<NewsSomeNewClass>> getNewsSentimentIndexes()//new class for exmaple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I can see in your parameters, it has some parameters belong to the data itself (e.g. item ids, names etc) and some parameters belong to the query (e.g. from/to, order by, page, take etc).

So, I would say that you can use the parameters directly or create the classes for it. It's up to you.

Just keep in mind that if you will have, let's say, 10 parameters, and some of them will be optional, it could lose the readability (it's just my thoughts).

In case with classes, you will be able to create the class hierarchy, where base class could contain some parameters which is in use for different endpoints.

I think, that the same could be applied to classes that will be used to return the data.

Hope it will help.